# Weird Character while reading from file C++

Tags: c++, file, parsing, split

I keep getting weird character at beginning when reading from inv.txt file. I googled with for a while but cannot find the solution for it. Below is the is my code and also content of the file

```
void installDataToInventory(string fileName) {


// Open file to read data
std::ifstream myFile;
myFile.open(fileName);

// Continue if file is open 
if (myFile.is_open()) {
    std::string line;
    // initial count to for putting book info 
    // to approriate slot of inventory array 
    int count = 0;

    // Loop through the end of the file 
    while (getline(myFile, line)) {
        // Ignore empty line in data file
        if (line == "") continue; 
        std::stringstream iss_line(line);
        iss_line.clear();
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
        //std::cout << iss
        // declare array with size 10 
        // each slot of array represend one field in Book 
        // book[0] - ISBN
        // book[1] - title 
        // book[2] - author 
        // book[3] - publisher
        // book[4] - quantity 
        // book[5] - wholesale 
        // book[6] - retail price
        // book[7] - day
        // book[8] - month
        // book[9] - year 
        std::string arrayString[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            std::getline(iss_line, arrayString[i], '|');
        }

    } 
 }
```

Below is content of inv.txt

```
978-1-60309-2395M|merican Elf 1999|James Kochalka|New York|465|12.53|14.94|22|2|1994
978-1-891830-37-2|The Barefoot Serpent (softcover)|Scott Morse|New York|338|20.41|23.06|29|9|1993
978-1-891830-40-2|Beach Safari|Mawil|Berkley|358|20.2|22.91|16|5|1994
978-1-891830-56-3|Bighead|Jeffrey Brown|Berkley|274|20.95|22.41|1|1|2017
978-1-891830-19-8|Box Office Poison|Alex Robinson|Berkley|576|19.09|21.21|13|1|2019
978-0-9713597-6-5|Clumsy|Jeffrey Brown|Berkley|878|16.02|18.92|6|10|1994
978-1-891830-81-5|Cry Yourself to Sleep|Jeremy Tinder|Berkley|63|11.6|14.54|13|3|2007
978-1-891830-12-9|Dear Julia|Hoa Handsome Ly|Berkley|517|12.91|16.2|14|11|2008
978-1-891830-92-1|Death Chocolate|Chocolate|Berkley|877|17.96|20.3|8|5|1999
978-1-891830-77-8|Every Girl is the End of the World for Me|Jeffrey Brown|Pittsburgh Publisher|524|14.25|16.17|16|2|2013
978-0-9585783-4-9|From Hell|Alan Moore|Pittsburgh Publisher|262|19.54|21.25|10|11|2000
978-1-891830-02-0|Hey Mister Vol 1|Mister|Pittsburgh Publisher|520|16.5|17.56|28|5|2001
978-1-891830-25-9|Hey Mister Vol 2|Mister|Pittsburgh Publisher|881|14.07|17.44|13|9|2012
978-1-891830-17-4|Hutch Owen (Vol 1): The Collected|Tom Hart|Pittsburgh Publisher|645|19.47|23.3|29|10|1999
978-1-891830-55-6|Hutch Owen (Vol 2): Unmarketable|Tom Hart|Pittsburgh Publisher|890|12.56|14.03|24|8|1997
978-1-891830-65-5|The King |Rich Koslowski|Pittsburgh Publisher|219|17.88|20.56|19|11|2014
978-1-891830-51-8|Less Than Heroes|David Yurkovich|Pittsburgh Publisher|218|16.61|19.04|3|8|2015
978-1-891830-69-3|Lone Racer|Nicolas Mahler|Sam Club|349|20.31|23.62|1|2|2014
978-1-891830-33-4|Magic Boy and the Robot Elf|James Kochalka|Sam Club|156|20.56|22.07|12|11|1991
978-1-891830-45-7|The Mirror of Love|Alan Moore|Sam Club|406|19.45|23.27|6|8|2002
978-1-891830-36-5|Monkey vs. Robot (Vol 2): Crystal of Power|Koch|Sam Club|94|18.33|22.02|7|3|2002
978-1-891830-68-6|Mosquito|Dan James|Sam Club|957|11.36|13.51|28|12|1997
978-1-891830-29-7|Pinky & Stinky|James Kochalka|Sam Club|725|14.93|17.54|24|8|2018
978-1-891830-14-3|Speechless|Peter Kuper|Sam Club|774|20.24|22.12|29|6|2006
978-1-891830-50-1|Spiral-Bound|Aaron Renier|Sam Club|594|15.7|18.9|5|9|2018
978-1-891830-31-0|Three Fingers|Rich Koslowski|Sam Club|584|12.12|14.15|27|2|2017
978-1-891830-70-9|The Ticking|Renée French|New York Times|221|18.4|22|16|2|2005
978-1-891830-04-4|Top Shelf #7: On Parade Edited|Warnock|New York Times|264|20.65|24.6|20|3|2013
978-1-891830-11-2|Top Shelf #8: Under the Big Top|Brett Warnock|New York Times|245|19.69|23.23|3|8|2016
978-1-891830-32-7|Top Shelf #9: Asks the Big Questions Edited|Warnock|New York Times|503|18.6|21.36|6|2|2002
978-1-891830-73-0|Tricked|Alex Robinson|New York Times|102|14.15|17.06|18|3|1999
978-1-891830-41-9|Unlikely|Jeffrey Brown|New York Times|216|19.64|23.63|1|5|2003
978-1-891830-38-9|Van Helsing's Night Off|Nicolas Mahler|New York Times|178|11.91|15.87|29|10|2012
978-1-60309-035-3|Voice of the Fire|Alan Moore|New York Times|705|18.39|20.11|1|5|2005
978-1-891830-72-3|Will You Still Love Me If I Wet the Bed|Liz Prince|New York Times|832|15.7|17.76|8|12|2019
```

And, below is the output picture, it has the weird character at the beginning at the beginning when printing it out. 
[image]

Comment: If the file is text, why are you opening the file as binary?

Comment: I edited it, I put it like that while debugging and fixed it. Moreover, the problem still existed

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Where are you getting the file from? Was it produced on a different operating system? Unreadable characters are either out of range on the standard ascii table or are from ascii codes that produce commands such as CR/LF/NL...etc

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: https://wandbox.org/permlink/oI4g20UYKyVWmkSP

Comment: So, I was creating this the content in Linux, push it to git. Then, I pull it to window machine.

Comment: If it is the first two characters perhaps it is a BOM.

Comment: @EvOlaNdLuPiZ you are right, the problem laid on the formatting between Linux and Window. I re-created the file in window and the problem was gone.

Comment: unix2dos should fix this or fix it in notepad++ on windows.

Comment: You can handle further encoding by setting logic for further ascii characters. Similarly if you’re reading things into a buffer I’d suggest you ensure the buffer is cleared before filling it up. Static keyword should do the trick or iterate over the buffer and perfil with all 0’s, or whatever you want in it.

Comment: Smells like the byte-order-marks (BOM) as Retired Ninja pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re creating the file on a different OS than the one you’re reading it on then you will likely get encoding issues, as such.There are various ways around this, some: clear the buffer you’re reading your file into, parse the file for out of range ascii characters and recreate the file without.